# Local scripts conflict with builtin modules when loading numpy

Tags: python, numpy, anaconda, conda

There are many posts about relative/absolute imports issues, and most of them are about Python 2 and/or importing submodules. **This is not my case**:

- I am using Python 3, so absolute import is the default;
- (I have also reproduced this issue with Python 2);
- I am not trying to import a submodule from within another submodule, or any other complicated situation. I am just trying to `import numpy` in a script.

My problem is simple:

```
.
└── foo
    ├── a.py
    └── math.py

1 directory, 2 files
```

where `a.py` just contains `import nupmy`, and `math.py` contains `x++` (intentionally invalid).

In that case, running `python3 foo/a.py` causes an error, due to NumPy seemingly not being able to import the standard `math` module:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "foo/a.py", line 1, in <module>
    import numpy
  File "/path/to/Anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 158, in <module>
    from . import add_newdocs
  File "/path/to/Anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "/path/to/Anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/lib/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    import math
  File "/private/tmp/test-import/foo/math.py", line 1
    x++
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I am relatively inexperienced with Python, but this looks like a bug to me. I thought statements like `import math` in Python 3 behaved as absolute imports; how can a local file conflict with a standard module? Am I doing something wrong?

**To clarify, what I find surprising is that NumPy is unable to load the standard math module with `import math`, because I have a file in my local folder named `math.py`.** Note that I never try to import that module myself.

---

**EDIT**

<strike>This seems to be an issue specific to `conda` (reproduced with both Anaconda and Miniconda). I am using Anaconda 5.2.0 (on OSX 10.13.6), and people in comments have been able to reproduce with different versions of python/anaconda, and different systems.</strike>

I was able to reproduce this issue with:

- Anaconda3 v5.2.0, using python 3.4, 3.5, 3.6 and 3.7, within a `conda` environment, or simply using the default binaries (ie `/path/to/anaconda3/bin`).
- Miniconda2, and Miniconda3 (manual install of `numpy` required), again either within or outside a `conda` environment.
- A clean Homebrew install `brew install python`.

In all cases, it looks like the builtin-modules might be incomplete:

```
> python3 -c "import sys; print(sys.builtin_module_names)"
('_ast', '_codecs', '_collections', '_functools', '_imp', '_io', '_locale', '_operator', '_signal', '_sre', '_stat', '_string', '_symtable', '_thread', '_tracemalloc', '_warnings', '_weakref', 'atexit', 'builtins', 'errno', 'faulthandler', 'gc', 'itertools', 'marshal', 'posix', 'pwd', 'sys', 'time', 'xxsubtype', 'zipimport')

> python2 -c "import sys; print sys.builtin_module_names"
('__builtin__', '__main__', '_ast', '_codecs', '_sre', '_symtable', '_warnings', '_weakref', 'errno', 'exceptions', 'gc', 'imp', 'marshal', 'posix', 'pwd', 'signal', 'sys', 'thread', 'xxsubtype', 'zipimport')
```

---

**REPRODUCE THIS ISSUE**

Make sure you have a version of Python that can import numpy. Open a terminal and type:

```
D=$(mktemp -d)                      # temporary folder
pushd "$D"                          # move there 
mkdir foo                           # create subfolder
echo 'import numpy' >| foo/a.py     #   script a.py
echo 'x++' >| foo/math.py           #   script math.py (invalid)
python foo/a.py                     # run a.py
popd                                # leave temp folder
```

Comment: the Traceback doesn't have anything to do with imports, it's clearly saying `invalid syntax`, remove that `x++` and you should be good to go

Comment: @SashaTsukanov Are you confident this is the case? I know Python has a few "invasive" requirements (e.g. brackets, spaces, etc), and that keywords can typically not (sanely) be used as variables, but restricting the name of local files seems overly invasive.

Comment: @MousaHalaseh I don't think you understand the issue. NumPy should not be importing the local `math.py`; instead, `import math` should resolve to the standard `math` module.

Comment: @Sheljohn that's not a restriction of the language, that's how the import mechanism works. There is no built-in list of stdlib modules. If you want module "math", Python will look through `sys.path` in order, and the first "math" it finds is your module.

Comment: @matejcik Then I think this is a bug with the import mechanism; local paths should always come after standard paths. This is the whole point behind "absolute imports" as a default!

Comment: The documentation also states  "When a module named spam is imported, the interpreter first searches for a built-in module with that name" (https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path). So python should not import the local file, even though it seems to do so.

Comment: @jdamp Finally, a useful comment :)

Comment: @jdamp you're confusing "built-in module" with "standard library module". Built-in names are things like `open`, or, in this case, module `builtins`. These are part of the interpreter itself. But most of the library lives in its own files.

Comment: @matejcik I don't think you read the link.

Comment: Huh. Well, regardless of what I wrote, `math` is actually a built-in, so this really _should_ work. And interestingly enough, for me it works exactly as you expect it should. Can you run `python3 -c "import sys; print(sys.builtin_module_names)"` and see if `math` is in the output?

Comment: @Sheljohn  I can reproduce the behavior you observe only with anaconda's python (both python 3.5 and 3.6), while it works fine for me with the builtin python3.5 on Ubuntu. So this issue might actually be anaconda specific.

Comment: @jdamp Yes, running the command suggested by matejcik also gives a ridiculously small list of built-ins; I think there is definitely an issue with the installation. I have updated the title + tags. How can I report this to Anaconda?

Comment: Interesting issue, +1. I could not reproduce it with Anaconda 4.4, though. Can you put the list of builtin modules in the question (i.e. the output of matejcik's suggested command)

Comment: @MattMessersmith Please see edits.

Comment: Hold on there, which bin are you using, `python3` or `python`? Are they aliased to the same thing? i.e. output of `which python3`

Comment: @MattMessersmith I deleted all my envs and am in the process of creating new ones from scratch. `python3` and `python` link to the same executable `python3.6` in Anaconda 5.2.0 (run `readlink /path/to/Anaconda3/bin/python`).

Comment: Well, that's a real bugger. I think you are right, it looks like a bug in the anaconda interpreter. If it matters, I am also on windows, not linux.

Answer (score 0):

"Absolute import" does not mean "standard library import". It means that `import math` always tries to import the `math` module, rather than the old behavior of trying `currentpackage.math` first if the import occurs inside a package. It does *not* mean that Python will skip non-stdlib entries on `sys.path` when figuring out where the `math` module is. In your situation, by the rules of the Python import system, your `math.py` is the `math` module.

---

The tutorial link you found with the line

> When a module named spam is imported, the interpreter first searches for a built-in module with that name.

is referring to modules that are *directly compiled into the Python executable*, like `sys`. Such modules say `built-in` in their `repr`:

```
>>> sys
<module 'sys' (built-in)>
```

You can see the names of all such modules in [`sys.builtin_module_names`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.builtin_module_names). For me, those names are

```
>>> sys.builtin_module_names
('_ast', '_codecs', '_collections', '_functools', '_imp', '_io', '_locale', '_operator', '_signal', '_sre', '_stat', '_string', '_symtable', '_thread', '_tracemalloc', '_warnings', '_weakref', 'atexit', 'builtins', 'errno', 'faulthandler', 'gc', 'itertools', 'marshal', 'posix', 'pwd', 'sys', 'time', 'xxsubtype', 'zipimport')
```

`math` isn't built-in in that sense.

Comment: My modules are not packaged, and I am only importing numpy, not the math module. The fact that _NumPy_ is unable to import the standard math module by writing `import math`, because I have a file named `math.py` in my local folder, is completely insane.

Comment: @Sheljohn: There are certainly annoyances in the Python import system. (Personally, I've always hated how easy it is to wind up with three distinct modules created from the same file.) What you're seeing is a consequence of how local files get dumped into the same top-level module namespace as stdlib and installed modules. Python wasn't designed with the whole stdlib in a `std` package like C++'s `std` namespace, and there's no implicit package for local files or anything like that to keep local files out of top-level.

Comment: I wish it was just a matter of annoyance, but this actually means we are constantly hacking the modules we load, by (potentially silently) hiding the modules that _they_ load. If `sys` is a built-in though, does this mean it cannot be shadowed by local files, e.g. when writing: `import sys; sys.path = list(reversed(sys.path))` ?